# Using os module in python to write scripts

Tags: python-2.7, module

What is the use of os module in python?
When one needs to use it and what type of functions are there which are mostly used to write linux scripts?

Comment: [Python Module of the Week: `os` – Portable access to operating system specific features.](http://pymotw.com/2/os/index.html#module-os)

Answer (score 0):

os module is very useful i will give example of my script .

```
import os,platform,time 
info=os.uname()
result={'OS':info[0],'Network id':info[1],'Release':info[2],'Os Name':''.join(list(info[3].split()[0])[4:]),'Machine Type':info[4],'System Bit':platform.architecture()[0],'System Linkage':platform.architecture()[1]}
w = open("rapport.rpt", "w")
for key, val in result.items():
    w.writelines([key,' : ',val,'\n','*'*3,"*"*len(key),'*'*len(val),'\n'])
w.writelines([time.ctime(),'!'])
print ('Exporting......')
time.sleep(1.5)
w.close()
print ('operation Finished!',w.name)
```